# Proof of existence of some linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I recently trained in linear algebra and got stuck with this problem. I don't know from which side to start solving this problem and how to push it forward. Can anyone give me some advice or guidance?  Thank you in advance!

Let $V$ be a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.  Prove that there exist $1≤i_{1}< i_{2}< ... <i_{k}≤n$ such that the mapping $F:\mathbb R^n→\mathbb R^k$ given by $F(\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
... \\
x_{n}
\end{pmatrix})$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
x_{i_1}\\
x_{i_2}\\
... \\
x_{i_k}
\end{pmatrix}$ when truncated to $V$ is an isomorphism of $V→\mathbb R^k$

Comment: what is your $i_k$ ?

Comment: There is a problem in the statement of the problem. You don't use the indexes $i_1,...,i_k$. I guess it should be $F(x_1,...,x_k) = (x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k})$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I already edited. thank you

Comment: Do we assume the standard basis?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. There are no restrictions about the base.

Comment: I believe there are two close votes because the problem seems to come out of nowhere. It is a small problem so I personally want vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1,\dots,v_k$ be a basis for $V$. Write $A$ as the $n \times k$ matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_k$. Then the matrix $A$ has rank $k$ (because it has $k$ linearly independent columns!).

Recall that the rank of a matrix and its transpose are the same, so $A^\top$, which is the $k \times n$ matrix where $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are the rows, also has rank $k$. So we should be able to find $k$ linearly independent columns of $A^\top$ (or equivalently, $k$ linearly independent rows of $A$). Let $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k$ be the indices of these columns of $A^\top$ (rows of $A$).

Since rows $i_1,\dots,i_k$ of $A$ are independent, the square sub-matrix consisting of these rows has non-zero determinant.

Consider the map $F(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_k})$ restricted to $V$. Note that the matrix of $F$ with respect to the basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ of $V$ and the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^k$ is exactly the matrix described in the last paragraph: the square sub-matrix of $A$ consisting of rows $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k$. Since its determinant is non-zero, the map is invertible (i.e an isomorphism).